# Why does MongoDB timeout on client.connect?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, error-handling, connection-timeout

I am trying to connect to my mongodb from node/express and I am receiving a connection timed out error when trying to connect. This is the code I am working with atm to find the solution.

```
    await client.connect().then((res:any) => console.log(res)
```

And this is the error code given.

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT 52.64.110.205:27017
```

So far I have tried adding additional timeout params including

keepAlive=true&socketTimeoutMS=360000&connectTimeoutMS=360000

I have also tried connecting to another cluster with a different username/password and received the same error. I don't think it's an error with env variables as all the other .env variables are working. And I think it might be worth mentioning that this function was working for the first day or two after I put it in.

Below is the entire function. I have commented some parts out for debugging purposes.It returns the same error either way, so I assume it can only be something to do with the connection.

```
export const handleCreateRequestDB = async (input: any) => {
    console.log(`creating new user in DB @ ${input}`)
    const createUserAccount = async (client: any, newUser: object) => {
        await client.connect().then((res:any) => console.log(res)
            // await client.db('onlinestore').collection('user_data').insertOne(newUser).then((result: any) => {
            //     console.log(result)
                // return result
            // })
        )
    }
    try {
        
            createUserAccount(client, input)
                .then((result) => {return result})
        

    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        return false
    }
    // finally {
    //     await client.close()
    // }
}
```

Comment: Is this a locally installed mongodb server?

Comment: I think it's an AWS cluster

Comment: What are the chances of my IP changing within a week?

Comment: It depends on your ISP but I'd say pretty high. Sometimes I can have the same IP for a month and other times for a couple of days but about a week is when you'd expect it to change

Comment: My ISP changes my IP addresses every day at 2 AM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the help from everyone here, I was able to solve the issue. It appears that my IP had changed since I had created the Atlas and to fix this I just needed to add my updated IP address. It also appears that a connection timed out error from mongo can be caused by access restrictions, such as username/password or in my case, IP ban from my own service.